# div wont fill 100% width on mobile Chrome/Safari Browser

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple website where the header is stretching 100% wide of the browser, then have the content below the header to be 1100px wide centered. This is working perfectly fine on desktop browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox). On mobile however there is issues. I haven't done any responsive CSS, but the image in the header should still fill the width of the browser. Here is my code related to this header.

HTML:

```
<div class="featured" style="background-image:url('image.jpg');" onclick="location.href='#';">
    <div class="featured-details">
        <h2><a href="#">Headline</a></h2>
        <p>Some text goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.featured {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position:center center; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 100;
}

.featured-details {
  color: #ebebeb;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 1100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 150;
}
```

As you can see it works fine on desktop: http://sistestopp.com/uploads/desktop.png

But on mobile the header isn't 100%: http://sistestopp.com/uploads/mobile.png
(the footer is doing the same stuff).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah sorry, the temporary URL is http://sistestopp.com/ny/

Comment: you want your header image stretched till other content div in mobile view or what?

Comment: but if you want to make your header images responsive then use background-size:100%..still not sure about your point so tell us exactly what the issue is..thanx

Comment: If you look at the mobile screenshot you can see that the header image (with the sheep) doesn't fill the full with of the browser. I just want it to stretch all the way out to the right. It works perfectly on all desktop browsers, but mobile browsers seem to have an issue with this. See screenshot here: http://sistestopp.com/uploads/mobile.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is in `div.container`. Its width is fixed at 1100px. In mobile device has resolution width smaller than that number, browser must scale to show the whole page and then your problem appear. If you add this line to header, you will see it clearly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

Solution is very simple

```
.container{
    /*width: 1100px;*/
    max-width: 1100px;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Can't belive it was that simple. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to use this where the wrapper width is 100%, with a 1020px inner container and upper/lower contents that stretch to viewport width. I was getting a cutoff on the right that only goes away if I set wrapper width to 104%.

With this method, I basically get it zoomed to the top left corner. Does this only work with specific pixel widths? Is there a way to achieve the same effect with a 100% width?

Comment: if you don't want something be overflow or hidden on responsive device, just don't hard code element width. You could try to style your 1020px container to `max-width: 1020px`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i got your point then solution for that.
Add this css with background image

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
```

and your this class .featured-details should have width:100% or else the heading text will disturb your header image..

chech this screenshot..[image]
Hope i was able to help or else if any issue then let me know..

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use CSS 3 vh and vw here.

```
width:100vw;
```

> Check more about vh and vw in the below links.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Comment: That doesn't really seem to change anything on mobile. Still looks the same on desktop though so thats good.

Comment: @user1951116 if you want to stretch the header image like div content then you have to take div content width in %..because header is managing size according to screen as width in % but content div's width is in px so it is stretched beyond the screen..